# How to solve Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $ when launching the app?

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm new in using <kbd>RETROFIT</kbd> with <kbd>Jetpack Compose</kbd>. i'm stuck at a point where i make a request to API and the <kbd>API</kbd> gave me this result. I want to get the data inside <kbd>"administrative"</kbd> key.

```
// 20230128172744
// https://api.bigdatacloud.net/data/reverse-geocode-client?latitude=-6.16991&longitude=106.8310533&localityLanguage=id

{
  "latitude": -6.16991,
  "longitude": 106.8310533,
  "continent": "Asia",
  "lookupSource": "coordinates",
  "continentCode": "AS",
  "localityLanguageRequested": "id",
  "city": "Jakarta",
  "countryName": "Indonesia",
  "countryCode": "ID",
  "postcode": "",
  "principalSubdivision": "Jakarta",
  "principalSubdivisionCode": "ID-JK",
  "plusCode": "6P58RRJJ+2C",
  "locality": "Sawah Besar",
  "localityInfo": {
    "administrative": [
      {
        "name": "Indonesia",
        "description": "negara di Asia Tenggara dan Oseania",
        "order": 2,
        "adminLevel": 2,
        "isoCode": "ID",
        "wikidataId": "Q252",
        "geonameId": 1643084
      },
      {
        "name": "Jakarta",
        "description": "ibu kota Indonesia sampai tahun 2024",
        "order": 7,
        "adminLevel": 4,
        "wikidataId": "Q3630",
        "geonameId": 1642911
      },
      {
        "name": "Jakarta",
        "description": "ibu kota Indonesia sampai tahun 2024",
        "order": 8,
        "adminLevel": 4,
        "isoCode": "ID-JK",
        "wikidataId": "Q3630",
        "geonameId": 1642907
      },
      {
        "name": "Jakarta Pusat",
        "description": "kota administratif di Provinsi DKI Jakarta, Indonesia",
        "order": 9,
        "adminLevel": 5,
        "wikidataId": "Q10109",
        "geonameId": 1642908
      },
      {
        "name": "Sawah Besar",
        "description": "kecamatan di Kota Jakarta Pusat, DKI Jakarta",
        "order": 10,
        "adminLevel": 6,
        "wikidataId": "Q192865",
        "geonameId": 6754659
      }
    ],
    "informative": [
      {
        "name": "Asia",
        "description": "Benua terbesar dan berpenduduk paling banyak di dunia, terletak sebagian besar di belahan bumi timur dan utara",
        "order": 1,
        "isoCode": "AS",
        "wikidataId": "Q48",
        "geonameId": 6255147
      },
      {
        "name": "Kepulauan Melayu",
        "description": "istilah usang untuk merujuk kepada gabungan kepulauan di Asia Tenggara",
        "order": 3,
        "wikidataId": "Q208643",
        "geonameId": 1636682
      },
      {
        "name": "Kepulauan Sunda Besar",
        "description": "Gugusan Kepulauan di Indonesia",
        "order": 4,
        "wikidataId": "Q165481",
        "geonameId": 1643789
      },
      {
        "name": "Jawa",
        "description": "pulau di Indonesia",
        "order": 5,
        "isoCode": "ID-JW",
        "wikidataId": "Q3757",
        "geonameId": 1642673
      },
      {
        "name": "Java",
        "order": 6
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

When i tried with the solution i found at google the app give me this result: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $.

This is my ApiService code looks like

```
data class Todo(
    var continent: String,
    var city: String,
    var countryName: String,
    var locality: String
)

const val BASE_URL = "https://api.bigdatacloud.net/data/"

public interface APIService {
    @GET("reverse-geocode-client?latitude=-6.16991&longitude=106.8310533&localityLanguage=id")
    suspend fun getTodos(): List<Todo>
    companion object {
        var apiService: APIService? = null
        fun getInstance(): APIService {
            if (apiService == null) {
                apiService = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build().create(APIService::class.java)
            }
            return apiService!!
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my ViewModel code looks like.

```
class TodoViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _todoList = mutableStateListOf<Todo>()
    var errorMessage: String by mutableStateOf("")
    val todoList: List<Todo>
        get() = _todoList

    fun getTodoList() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val apiService = APIService.getInstance()
        try {
            _todoList.clear()
            _todoList.addAll(apiService.getTodos())

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            errorMessage = e.message.toString()
        }
    }
}
}
```

I've tried to change this line in ApiService to Call<Todo>

```
suspend fun getTodos(): List<Todo>
```

this line in ViewModel will give me error

```
_todoList.addAll(apiService.getTodos())
```

I will be appreciate any help.

i was expecting the app that i build not give me Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 pasth $ error and the app can display the data from JSON correctly.

Comment: It seems you are expecting a list of `Todo` but the service returns a single `Todo`

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what a `Todo` represents, when you say you really want the `administrative` data.  The API endpoint returns a single object let's call this a *Locality* and within that there is a collection of *Adminstrative* objects.

As Ken Wolf points out your code tries to deserialize a **List** where the `Todo` seems to partially represent a *Locality*.  So there are several things wrong.

The serializer is only going to return a single object from this JSON because the JSON begins with `{` but you code say to expect a List, and a JSON List starts with `[` - that's the error you are getting.

Once you remove `List` you may get a new error that some properites are not mapped (this depends on the deserializer settings), but anyway the model object you call `Todo` needs to have more properties if you are interested in a collection of *Adminstrative* objects, something like this:

```
data class Locality(
    val continent: String,
    val city: String,
    val countryName: String,
    val locality: String,
    val localityInfo: LocalityInfo,
)

data class LocalityInfo(
    val administrative: List<AdminstrativeInfo>
)

data class AdminstrativeInfo(
    val name: String, ....
)
```